# Using .htaccess, how to display another URL's content as if it were the current URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to display to the user content of another URL, when he goes to my url, but without changing the URL completely. Example:
When he goes to http://example.com I want him to see content of http://example.com/another/url
But I want him to believe (to see in the browser) his given URL.
How to do this using .htaccess? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/another/url/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /another/url [L]
```

This will load `/another/url` when you request `http://example.com/` in browser but will not change browser URL.